# Download returns a corrupted document (bottle + pymongo)?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, bottle, gridfs

I have a basic web form at '/add' that takes user input and uploads to a mongodb:

**PYTHON:**

```
@bottle.route('/add')
def add_page():
    return bottle.template('files_test/add')

@bottle.route('/upload', method='POST')
def do_upload():
    data = request.files.data
    if data:
        raw = data.file.read()  # This is dangerous for big files
        file_name = data.filename
        try:
            newfile_id = fs.put(raw, filename=file_name)
        except:
            return "error inserting new file"
    print(newfile_id)
    return bottle.redirect('/')
```

**add.tpl:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- pass in files (dict)-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Preformance and Capacity Management</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="data" /><br>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a page that displays the data, and downloads it:

**PYTHON:**

```
@bottle.route('/download')
def download():
    file_id = ObjectId(bottle.request.query.id)
    if file_id:
        try:
            file_to_download = fs.get(file_id)
        except:
            return "document id not found for id:" + file_id, sys.exc_info()[0]
        file_extension = str(file_to_download.name)[(str(file_to_download.name).index('.')):]


        response.headers['Content-Type'] = (mimetypes.types_map[file_extension])
        response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + file_to_download.name
```

**home.tpl:**

```
<body>

<br><br><br><br>
%for fileobj in files:
    Filename: {{fileobj['filename']}}<br>
    Size: {{fileobj['length']}}<br>
    Date Uploaded: {{fileobj['uploadDate']}}<br>
    md5: {{fileobj['md5']}}<br>
    <a href="download?id={{fileobj['_id']}}">&lt--Download File--&gt</a>
<br><br><br><br>
%end
</body>
```

When I try to download the files, it downloads them, but I cannot open them. For example, a text file with the words "test" inside will open up blank. An excel spreadsheet opens up corrupted.

Am I uploading or downloading wrong? or both? For full code, see [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42006/bottle-py-upload-document-to-mongodb) on Code Review.

Comment: Figured it out. Return the data itself (in my case, "file_to_download").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to the "server.py" file in the "download" function :

```
return file_to_download
```

I needed to set the HTTP headers and THEN return the raw data.